# moveBall function not working when adding input parameters

Tags: javascript, html, parameters

I'm trying to create a moveBall function were you put the ID of the ball created in HTML, and it moves from left to right.

This is what I've done first, and it works:

```js
var ball = document.getElementById("ball");

var velocityX = 100;
var positionX = 0;
var reverseX = false;


//write a function that can change the position of the html element "ball"

function moveBall() {
    // two fixed x-axis coordinates (you will use these variable in step 3)
    var Xmin = 0;
    var Xmax = 500;

  //reverse condition
  if (!reverseX){
  positionX = positionX + velocityX;
  } else positionX = positionX - velocityX;
  
  ball.style.left = positionX + 'px';
  
  if (positionX === Xmax){
    reverseX = true;
  } else if (positionX === Xmin){
    reverseX = false;
  }
  
  }
  
  // This call the moveBall function every 100ms
  setInterval(moveBall, 100);
```

However, when I try to make a function moveBall(ballId) so I can re use it with other balls, it doesn't work. This is my code:

```js
var ballId;

var velocityX = 100;
var positionX = 0;
var reverseX = false;


//write a function that can change the position of the html element "ball"

function moveBall(ballId) {
    
    ball = document.getElementById(ballId)
    
    // two fixed x-axis coordinates (you will use these variable in step 3)
    var Xmin = 0;
    var Xmax = 500;

  //reverse condition
  if (!reverseX){
  positionX = positionX + velocityX;
  } else positionX = positionX - velocityX;
  
  ball.style.left = positionX + 'px';
  
  if (positionX === Xmax){
    reverseX = true;
  } else if (positionX === Xmin){
    reverseX = false;
  }
  
  }
  
  // This call the moveBall function every 100ms
  setInterval(moveBall("ball"), 100);
```

Please I would be thrilled to know if you have any clue. The ball doesn't move with the second code, it just remains static in the html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the line which says `setInterval(moveBall("ball"), 100);`

`setInterval` expects a function as first argument, however, here provided is a function call instead. I'm a bit rusty on theory here, but basically this will execute function call first, which will return `undefined` and then your line looks same as if you have written `setInterval(undefined, 100);`, so every 100ms you do nothing...

What you wanna do instead is write function handler to pass into `setInterval` instead of function call.

You can do either arrow function `setInterval(() => moveBall("ball"), 100);`
or if you can't use arrow functions you could do `setInterval(function () {moveBall("ball")}, 100);`

This in other words says execute (nameless) function every 100ms, this nameless function will execute call of your `moveBall` function with desired paramater.

Your original code without param works since if you look closely, you are passing directly function there, without call.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Miroslav Saracevic for the incredibly quick answer,

```js
 // This call the moveBall function every 100ms
  setInterval(() => moveBall("ball"), 100)
```

This solved the problem.